# Exif field ImageDescription adding data is not fully successful

Tags: c#, exif

Hope to seek some help.
I am trying to add some text to Exif field ImageDescription(270). I am partially successful.
Here is the code

```
pitem.Id = 270;
  pitem.Type = 2;
      byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Testing ImageDescription from command line.");
      byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);
  pitem.Value = utf8Bytes;//utf16Bytes 
  image.SetPropertyItem(pitem);
```

I then save image copy at new path, then I try to read back the property just added. THIS is where I am so failing..:-(
For some reason this field is not taking more then 6 characters, I have tried many things including change data to UTF-8 byte array, adding null-terminator (\0), even tried another field (305) with the same issue there as well, field will not take more then 6 characters.. I am not being able to see the full text being added to the field. Can some one guide..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

(a) Look at [PropertyItem.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type.aspx) definition:

> 1: Specifies that Value is an array of bytes.
>
> 2: Specifies that Value is a null-terminated ASCII string. If you set the type data
>   member to ASCII type, you should set the Len property to the length of
>   the string including the null terminator. For example, the string
>   "Hello" would have a length of 6.

Looks like you are using it wrong - either it should be (1) - and then you should save array of bytes, or it should be (2) - but then you need to pass ASCII string to it.

Look at this question as well: [Set image meta data before save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396050/set-image-meta-data-before-save)

(b) Set ptype.Len property to the length of the string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.type.aspx

Comment: thanks...all I was missing was setting up the len property..:-)